# Error: File opened in Node.js JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some script on Node.js server.
It's opened some file, do something, and after that i try remove this file from storage with fs.unlink, but i got an error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 
If i try delete if manually, i got an error:

[Screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uxpL.png)

If i stop node.js app, or reload, error disappear, and i can delete this file.

How i can remove this file from Node.js JavaScript runtime, and remove it without error and crashes my app?

UPD:
I just parse .sqlite file trough knex.select("table_name")
And after that, fs.unlink() must remove that .sqlite file

Comment: Can you show us the code, where you open the file and try to close it?

Comment: Stop node JS run time in the terminal and remove the file.

Comment: you need to ["close"](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandleclose) it, before performing fs.unlink

Comment: @Geshode i update my question for more information

Comment: @Eng_Farghly i need do that from my script automatically, not in terminal of course

Comment: @bogdanoff did you mean fs.close(fd)? But i need fd. But i  just parse .sqlite file trough knex.select("table_name") And after that, fs.unlink() must remove that .sqlite file... how i can get fd here?...

Comment: Please show how you open the file

Comment: @kedO52 yes (fs.close), call fs.close just before calling fs.unlink, (hey check _konrad linkowski_ comment, thats seems right solution for knex)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thank you so much! It's works! Yes, i just need close knex connection to this file.

Comment: Glad I could help. Always remember to include some code samples in your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's difficult to say, but surely your file is still open. Try fs.close(fd, callback) before fs.unlink. However, I'd think your bug has to do with asynchronously performed code.

Comment: I try do some timeout on enough time, but file still is not available for removing, before i don't stop mu node.js service.

I update my question, with some code:

you mean fs.close(fd)? But i need fd. But i just parse .sqlite file trough knex.select("table_name") And after that, fs.unlink() must remove that .sqlite file... how i can get fd here?...